# Вывод текста до нажатия на кнопку(php html)

Tags: php, html, post, get

Совсем недавно познакомился с методами get и post, решил создать что то вроде формы регистрации, чтобы после заполнения полей и нажатия на кнопку выводилось сообщение "Данные сохранены", но вместо этого, сразу выполняется блок else(а когда его нету, выполняется блок if) Подскажите пожалуйста, в чем дело

```
<?php
$name = $_POST['$name'];
$login = $_POST['$login'];
$pass = $_POST['$password'];
if(isset($_POST['send']) && ( !empty($name)  && !empty($login) && !empty($pass))){
    echo 'Данные сохранены';
}
else{
    echo 'Заполните все поля';
}
?>
<form action="registration.php" method = 'post'>
    <label>
        Введите имя <input type = 'text' name = 'name' ><br><br>
        Введите логин <input type= "text" name = 'login'><br><br>
        Введите пароль <input type ='password' name = 'password'><br><br>
        <input type="submit" name = 'send'>
    </label>
</form>
```

Comment: В вашем коде нет блока `else`. Покажите, что приходит в `$_POST` после отправки формы. К тому же, у вас  `$_POST['$name']`, а надо  `$_POST['name']`.

Comment: Но это не сработало, я изменил код с $_POST['$name'] на $_POST['name'], но теперь сразу же срабатывает код в блоке if, даже до нажатия кнопки отправить

Comment: Попробуйте код из моего ответа, должно получиться. Если нет, то выведите `$_POST` на экран до и после отправки формы и прикрепите в тело вопроса для анализа.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Проблема кроется в том, что в `$_POST` вы пишете в качестве ключа `$name`. По сути, в самом `$_POST` нет такого ключа, но есть ключ `name`, который как раз приходит в закроме из формы: `<input type = 'text' name = 'name' >`.

Те названия, которые записаны в `name='...'` будут аналогично находится в `$_POST` или других вариациях.

Ваш код должен выглядеть примерно так:

```php
<?php if(array_key_exists('send', $_POST)): ?>
    <?php
        $name = trim($_POST['name']);
        $login = trim($_POST['login']);
        $pass = trim($_POST['password']);
        $dataIsFull = !empty($name) && !empty($login) && !empty($pass);
    ?>
    <?php if($dataIsFull): ?>
        <p>Данные сохранены</p>
    <?php else: ?>
        <p>Заполните все поля</p>
    <?php endif; ?>
<?php else: ?>
    <form action="registration.php" method = 'post'>
            <label for'name-input'>Введите имя </label>
        <input type = 'text' name = 'name' >
        <br><br>
            
        <label for'login-input'>Введите логин </label>
        <input type= "text" name = 'login'>
        <br><br>
        
            <label for'password-input'>Введите пароль </label>
        <input type ='password' name = 'password'>
        <br><br>        

        <input type="submit" name = 'send'>
    </form>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Здесь я внес небольшие корректировки:

1. Лучше всего создать отдельную переменную `$dataIsFull`, которая будет хранить результат условия всех проверок на полноту данных
2. [Конструкция](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/language.basic-syntax.phpmode.php) `if(...): else: endif;` полезная для разграничения кода.

Comment: Спасибо, всё работает. Но всё же я хочу разобраться в коде. Я вижу, что есть проверки на существования имени(переменной) send, на заполнение строк, но как код понимает, что мы нажали на кнопку? То есть у нас по идее, где то должна быть кнопка проверки на нажатие? Так же, я смотрел на ютубе, как другие создают такие форму, но у них почему то всё работало, я бы хотел узнать, как и где можно читать о таких серьезных изменениях в php?

Comment: Идет запрос на указанную страницу. В параметрах запроса есть данные и тип запроса от сервера. Это все конфигурируется в PHP в глобальные массивы. Изменения PHP - история развития + версионность на официальном сайте. Кстати, если хотите помочь сообществу, столкнувшемуся с аналогичной проблемой с правильным ответом, то можете отметить один из ответов как "решение" (галочка слева от ответа).